# How to parse this json in android studio?

Tags: java, android

```
{
  "result_count": 251175,
  "images": [
    {
      "id": "649682800",
      "display_sizes": [
        {
          "is_watermarked": false,
          "name": "thumb",
          "uri": "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/sergi-roberto-of-barcelona-celebrates-as-he-scores-their-sixth-goal-picture-id649682800?b=1&k=6&m=649682800&s=170x170&h=UjuhQ2k4pOnhCh5a1oLuC4t5rwX8332a-PEqZ8dpUfY="
        }
      ],
      "referral_destinations": [
        {
          "site_name": "gettyimages",
          "uri": "https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/sergi-roberto-of-barcelona-celebrates-as-he-scores-their-news-photo/649682800"
        }
      ],
      "title": "FC Barcelona v Paris Saint-Germain - UEFA Champions League Round of 16: Second Leg"
    }
```

Comment: If you want to parse to a java class you can youse gson or something similar.

Comment: Invalid json, make it in correct json format

Comment: Invalid Json, Kindly post your valid json... beofre posting your json text, check it first on this website https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: You can parse it manually with https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject or use gson.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file)

Comment: you are missing  `]}`  at the end of your json

Answer (score 0):

**The above JSON Data is missing `] }` . So make the data a valid JSON by adding `] }` at the end**

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("images");

    for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObjec = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
        jsonObjec.optString("id");
        jsonObjec.optString("title");

        JSONArray display_sizes = jsonObjec.optJSONArray("display_sizes");
        // get the display_sizes Array details

        JSONArray referral_destinations = jsonObjec.optJSONArray("referral_destinations");
        // get the referral_destinations Array details
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First it is invalid json.
Try using gson library to parse the json.

Try this link
[gson library to parse json](https://github.com/google/gson)